# Can we update the combined-flair for users with less than 200 rep on any sites?

Tags: feature-request, flair, combined-flair

In case you have no idea what I'm talking about, it's this:

> [image: You do not have any linked accounts with 200+ rep :(]

Now, if you compare that to the flair of someone who does, there are a few differences (I'm requesting that these be added to the flair pictured above):

- Username is not shown on this one
- No link to network-wide profile on this one
- It says `You...` but the flair is supposed to be for other users... isn't it? So it should say `[User] doesn't have any...`

Can this be changed?

I presume it says `You...` to tell you on the actual flair page, but what's the point of saying that again if it says the exact same thing underneath?:

> [image]

---

Mockup by @ShadowWizard:

> [image]

^^there's now the profile picture, username, and link to the profile.

Comment: Very rough mockup: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9hCeL.png (too lazy to change the text, just to show how I vison the design)

Comment: @Shadow nice :) It's simple and does everything important (the last bullet isn't so necessary :)